# LinearLayout not works as I want in XML Android

Tags: android, xml

***I want to arrange the my views in a column. Why can't I do it?  I tried some examples from the internet, but the are't work. Please help me, I'm begginer in XML.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:gravity="center"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phoneField"
        android:layout_width="149dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"


        android:hint="Телефон"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="235dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="308dp"

        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:hint="Email"

        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameField"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="496dp"


        android:hint="Имя"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.125"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password"

        android:layout_width="299dp"
        android:layout_height="118dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="REG"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="210dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="238dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_registration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="40dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="216dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't add filler text to bypass the quality filters. Those filters are in place because you're supposed to add details about the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, very funny the the reasons for that you pasted that strange text haha.

**About the problem:** Your linear layout is ok, but look at your views. They are effectively in a column but they are to separated because they measures are too large:

```
        android:layout_width="235dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="308dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
```

**1st:** Use width and height as wrap_content to match the size of the content of the view, in this case, the text.

**2nd:** Use small margings in this case 8dp is fine to see the views separated according.

**3rd:** The tools fields absolute X or Y are used for example in constraint layout to sort views without constraints, only in layout editor. Don't use it in this case because it will confuse you in layout editor.

Hope this helps, regards!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving width and height to a certain dp value, consider using "wrap_content" and "match_parent" so the system calculates it. It usually works and might be better because accounting for the different screen sizes is almost impossible or at least very difficult.

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65850924/7402956, there are some properties of constraint layout in the code. It doesn't work inside a Linear Layout.

Resources I found very useful for reference

Constraint Layout: https://constraintlayout.com/basics/

Linear Layout: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear

I modified the code removing absolute widths and heights. Removed margin top on some views as they were quite large to fit in the screen.

Sample code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/phoneField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:hint="Телефон"
    android:imeActionLabel="test-@string/action_sign_in_short"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:hint="Email"

    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:hint="Имя"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:hint="test-@string/prompt_password"
    android:imeActionLabel="test-@string/action_sign_in_short"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="REG"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_registration"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your marginTop values are too high (so do all other margin values)

```
android:layout_marginTop="308dp"
android:layout_marginTop="496dp"
```

Maybe your views went off screen. Decrease all margin values to adequate.
And remove all constraint Layout params by reason of your layout is linear, not constraint.